# Blazor question, regarding width percentage based on property

Tags: css, width, blazor, percentage, rating

I have a question regarding my width for my rating system on my Blazor  website. I want the stars to be based on the rating that my movie has. Like this :

[image]

Now I don't know how to use my movie.Rating property to set the width of the stars. I want it too look like this, but realize it doesn't work like that.

`div class="rating-upper" style="width:" @movie.Rating"%">`

My code looks like this (I have put 90% for now, but obviously want my rating there instead):

[image]

Thankful for any help and first time posting here since I can't find any info on this. New to Blazor as well and programming in general.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please copy-paste your code directly in the question instead of a picture of you code.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use the CSS clip-path for this, and structure things a little differently than you currently have.

First here is my CSS

```css
    .rating {        
        --rating: 0;
        --percent: calc(var(--rating) * 20%);
        position: relative;
        display: inline;
    }
    .rating::after {        
        position: absolute;
        content:"⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐";
        clip-path: polygon(0 0, var(--percent) 0, var(--percent) 100%, 0 100%);
        background-color: transparent;
        /* Purely cosmetic to align these stars vertically */
        top: -0.2rem; 
    }
    .rating::before {
        position: absolute;
        left: calc(100%);
        content:"⭐⭐⭐⭐⭐";
        opacity: 0.2;
        /* Purely cosmetic to align these stars vertically */
        top: -0.2rem;
    }
```

And some sample Razor

```html
<label class="rating" style=@($"--rating: {Rating}")>Rating : </label>
```

### Explanation

The class "rating" has a before and after that both add a set of stars to the content, they are positioned to overlap, with the background set at a low opacity and the foreground using clip-path to "mask" the stars to the required width.

The percentage width is calculated from the CSS variable `--rating` which is applied to the `label` using Razor syntax.

You can view a demo here : https://blazorfiddle.com/s/b6jpqbhe

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried doing it like you have done, but cant seem to get it to work. 

Should I use this line of code in my case?

<label class="rating" style=@($"--rating: {movie.Rating}")>Rating: </label>

When I do it like you have done above I always get five stars. Btw my movie.Rating is a double and ratings range from 0-5 so I would just like to take my rating and multple it by 20 to get a percentage from 0-100(I think that's what you have done in the code above).

Comment: You would probably used something like that in place of your div, or just adjust your div slightly

Comment: Sorry I was on my mobile before - the thing to watch out for with a div is that by default it will be 100% width, that's why I have `display: inline` in my CSS. So yours may be calculating a percentage, but that would default to a percentage of the whole div, which defaults to page width...